# How to show only online orders from the two options - direct and online?

Tags: oracle

I need to show the products which were only purchased online (order_mode = 'online') by removing the products which were purchased either direct OR direct AND online.

I tried with CASE, WHERE clauses but it didn't work

```
select p.product_name,
sum(o.quantity) as total_quantity,
case

when extract(month from p.warranty_period) = 0
    and extract(year from p.warranty_period) = 0 
        then 'No Warranty'
when extract(month from p.warranty_period) = 0
    then extract(year from p.warranty_period) || ' years'
when extract(year from p.warranty_period) = 0
    then extract(month from p.warranty_period) || ' months'
else extract(year from p.warranty_period) || ' years and ' ||
    extract(month from p.warranty_period) || ' months' 

 end WARRANTY, oe.order_mode from PRODUCT_INFORMATION p
join order_items o on p.product_id = o.product_id
join orders oe on o.order_id = oe.order_id
group by p.product_name, p.warranty_period, oe.order_mode
having sum(o.QUANTITY) > 200
order by p.product_name;
```

I expect to see the Order_mode column with only online purchases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no products meeting your requirement with a quantity > 200. I set the limit to 40.

```
select p.product_name,
sum(o.quantity) as total_quantity,
case
when extract(month from p.warranty_period) = 0
    and extract(year from p.warranty_period) = 0 
        then 'No Warranty'
when extract(month from p.warranty_period) = 0
    then extract(year from p.warranty_period) || ' years'
when extract(year from p.warranty_period) = 0
    then extract(month from p.warranty_period) || ' months'
else extract(year from p.warranty_period) || ' years and ' ||
    extract(month from p.warranty_period) || ' months' 

 end WARRANTY, 'online' order_mode from PRODUCT_INFORMATION p
join (
  select o.product_id, sum(o.quantity) quantity
  from order_items o
  join orders oe on o.order_id = oe.order_id
  group by o.product_id
  having sum(case oe.order_mode when 'direct' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
  and sum(o.quantity) > 40
) o on p.product_id = o.product_id
group by p.product_name, p.warranty_period
order by p.product_name;

PRODUCT_NAME           TOTAL_QUANTITY   WARRANTY               ORDER_MODE   
Chemicals - SW                     68   5 years                online        
DIMM - 32MB                        47   6 months               online        
PS 220V /HS/FR                     45   9 months               online        
Pens - 10/FP                       42   No Warranty            online        
Plastic Stock - B/HD               64   No Warranty            online        
TD 7GB/8                           59   1 years and 6 months   online
```